# Query returning results when it shouldn't | DocumentDB

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

when running below query it's returning records from collection:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Families f 
WHERE f.id = "AndersenFamily"
```

I tried in C# also and got same results:

```
query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionLink, new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                QueryText = "SELECT * FROM Families f WHERE (f.id = @name)",
                Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()  {
                          new SqlParameter("@name", "AndersenFamily")
                     }
            });
```

What's the significance of "Families"? ASFAIK it's not db name, collection name ,or any document name then why it's returning results?

I also tried to replace "Families" with some different word and I still got the results.

You can see the code here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sql-query

Comment: Are you seeing that when running the query from C#, or only in the Playground? If it's in the playground, it's probably a playground-specific aspect and unrelated to C#. (I strongly suspect this has nothing to do with C# or .NET either way, to be honest.)

Comment: @Skeet it's in C# code. I've updated the question.

Comment: Hmm. Given the behaviour in the playground, I still think this is really *just* a DocumentDb question, and knowledge of .NET and C# is irrelevant. The documentation isn't terribly clear to be honest - although it does say that the FROM clause is optional in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB supports querying using SQL syntax but since it actually is a NoSQL storage, the concept of tables does not exist.

When structuring a SQL query on DocumentDB, the `FROM` clause (which is optional) [specifies the source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn782250.aspx#bk_from_clause) which can contain the collection name and an alias.

In the case of your example, `Families` is acting as the collection name and `f` is acting as an alias. If you are creating a query against a single collection (which is the most common case), you don't really need to specify the collection name, you can simply use a reference to the collection contents (documents) like so:

`SELECT * FROM f WHERE f.id = "AndersenFamily"`

My opinion is that the `Families` reference is made so folks coming from a SQL scenario can relate to the query structure (looks like referencing a table).